# How to show container in listview using wrap

Tags: flutter, listview, containers

I'm trying to show `title` in box, and i want two box in a row, but it is not working, i'm using `ListView.builder`

here is the code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                color: Color(int.parse(bodycolor)),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                         SizedBox40(),
                         Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Choose any one Business", style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize:20)),
                    ),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: books.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final book = books[index];
                            return Wrap(  
                          spacing: 20.0,
                          runSpacing: 40.0,
                              children:[
                               InkWell( child: Container(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.15,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4, 
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(10),
                              ), ),
                              child:Text(book.title))),
                              SizedBox20(),
                              ]
                            
                              );
                            }),
                             SizedBox20(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

here is the snap

[image]

it shows in vertically, i want them 2 in row. please help if anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `Listview.builder`, you can use `GridView.builder`

```
GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2 // don't forget to use cross count
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20),
            itemCount: myProducts.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(myProducts[index]["name"]),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              );
            }),
```

Complete source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Hide the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Kindacode.com',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Map> myProducts =
  List.generate(100000, (index) => {"id": index, "name": "Product $index"})
      .toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter test'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20),
            itemCount: myProducts.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(myProducts[index]["name"]),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

N.B: Don't forget to use `crossAxisCount`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridView`.

```dart
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final book = books[index];
     
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(book.title),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```